# Make left and right margins equal when outer component is not known

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to display the following image centered:

[image]

I have the following style item:

```
var itemStyle = {
  display: 'block',
  width: this.computeWidth(),
  height: '250px',
  backgroundImage: 'url(' + imageLocation + ')',
  backgroundPosition: 'center !important',
  backgroundSize: 'cover',
  boxShadow: '10px 10px 5px #888888',
  borderRadius: '15px',
  marginLeft: 'auto !important',
  marginRight: 'auto !important'
};
```

Which I display like this:

```
<div style={itemStyle}>
</div>
```

`this.computeWidth()` is this method, where I resize the width of the image depending on the page:

```
  computeWidth: function() {
    console.log("this.state.window.width: " + this.state.window.width);
    if(this.state.window.width > 350) {
      return '250px';
    }
    return Math.floor(0.7 * this.state.window.width).toString() + 'px';
  },
```

I also tried computing `marginLeft` and `marginRight` using this method:

```
  computeMargin: function() {
      if(this.state.window.width > 350) {
        return 'margin-auto';
      }
      return Math.floor(0.15 * this.state.window.width).toString() + 'px';
  },
```

However, the image was not centered again.

So how can I make sure that the image is central to the page?(preferably without changing the `css` of the component containing it)

Comment: Are you positioning the element or the **background**-image, its not clear. Centering elements has **thousands** of related questions you could be checking.

Comment: The `backgroundImage`. But it's the same thing, isn't it? Because the background image occupies the entire element.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with `margin: Xpx auto`? It should work, because the image as defined width. Alternatively, you can add `flexbox` properties to the parent in order to center the child:

```
.parent {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS should be enough to solve this problem. Wrap the image in a `div` and center that with margin property.

```
<div class="img-wrap">
     <img src="foo.jpg">
</div>
```

```
.img-wrap { margin: 0 auto; }
```

Refer here for more detail: [CSS-Tricks centering guide](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/)

---

***Edit***
 - For centered background image apply the following CSS to the div:

```
background-image: url("foo.jpg");
background-position: 50% 50%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: contain;    /* Full image in div, no cropping, preserve aspect ratio */
```

This centers the image by moving the image's center halfway along both axes (x and y) in the div. Thus, perfect centering.

---

Alternatively, use this for hero images:

```
background-size: cover;      /* Fill div (even if img is cropped), preserve aspect ratio */
```

**More for background centering: [Sitepoint: background-position property](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/background-position-css-property/)**

Comment: I need to keep the image as background.